# Select Options not displayed when used with dynamic data from Rest client. Using Angular 6 and Bootstrap for UI

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm not able to display data in Select option dropdown when I try to populate data using Rest client.

Here's the code for Select option-

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" title="Choose Project" data-live-search="true" ng-model="">
    <option value="null">Choose Project</option>
    <option *ngFor="let project of projectList">{{project.projectname}}</option>
</select>
```

The code in Angular's .ts file is -

```
projectList: Project[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.queryService.retrieveProjectInfo().subscribe((data: any) => {
       this.projectList = data ;
    }); }
```

The code calling the service -

```
retrieveProjectInfo() {
const username = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
return this.httpClient.get(environment.sourceDbIrisUrl + 'getRelatedProjects/' + username); }
```

I understand that subscribe returns an Observable object, which in turn gets assigned to UI component whenever the value is returned.

If I try to populate projectList in a static way, I get the values in Select option -

```
projectList: Project[] = [
{projectname: 'ABC', projectid: 'A1'},
{projectname: 'XYZ', projectid: 'B1'}];
```

I'm just not getting the values while I populate Select's options in dynamic way.
But with same kind of mechanism, I populate data in a Data Table.

So, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with Select options.

P.S.- I'm new to Angular and UI development. :)

Comment: try to log the return value of the service call:  console.debug('Loaded data', JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t"));

Comment: @keuleJ Tried that before, suspecting [ ] issue with data. I tried putting a dummy value to the list, then popping it and assigning the data from service. With that as well, it shows the dummy value. May be I'm wrong but I suspect that the UI is not getting refreshed.